# What is the SSRS expression for end day of week?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have the following MSSQL query to return the ending day of the week in MSSQL:

```
SELECT DateAdd(Day, 0 - DatePart(Weekday, GetDate()), GetDate());
```

I played around with the `=DateAdd` function, but it keeps throwing me an error for the Day parameter. Also, when I used `DateInterval.Day`... I get the same error.

However, when I try placing that query into an SSRS expression, it throws me an error. Does anyone know the direct conversion for that query above in SSRS?

Comment: By end day of a week, do you mean the last day of a given week?

Comment: Remember, end day of week can be culturally dependent.  For example in U.S. culture, Sunday is taken to be the first day of the week, and thus Saturday would be the last or end day of the week.  Other cultures may vary -- or even organizations or companies (my Timesheet starts on Wednesday for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSRS Uses a dialect of Visual Basic, its Date functions are different from TSQL, you have to use

- "d" instead of DAY for day interval
- "w" instead of WEEKDAY for weekday
- Now() instead of GetDate() for current date.

Try

```
=DateAdd("d", 0 - DatePart("w", Now()), Now())
```